# Routing based on Media Type in ASP.Net MVC 5 / Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Consider the example of following actions in a controller with [RoutePrefix("api/some-entity")] attribute. The request is all same except for the value of "Content-Type" header and of-course the body content.

```
[HttpPost()]
[RequestHeaderMatchesMediaType("Content-Type",
new[] { "application/vnd.company.sampleDto.v1+json" })]
[Route("{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Fork([FromUri]string id, [FromBody]sampleDto dto){
   return Ok();
}

[HttpPost()]
[RequestHeaderMatchesMediaType("Content-Type",
new[] { "application/vnd.company.otherDto.v1+json" })]
[Route("{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Fork([FromUri]string id, [FromBody]otherDto dto){
   return Ok();
}
```

I want to route on the bases of header values. What should be the implementation of such an attribute.

Comment: I found [this](https://massivescale.com/web-api-routing-by-content-type/) link. Sounds like it does what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @telli. That's exactly what I was looking for.